# How do I load a resource string using an indirect string?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, resourcebundle

I'm trying to convert the indirect strings in the `Grouping` property of the firewall rules returned by `HNetCfg.FwPolicy2`. In PowerShell:

```
$fw = New-Object -ComObject 'HNetCfg.FwPolicy2'
$fw.Rules | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'Grouping' | Select-Object -Unique
```

Returns what the [MSDN docs refer to as "indirect strings"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365357(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
@mqutil.dll,-6102
@%windir%\system32\inetsrv\iisres.dll,-30503
@%windir%\system32\inetsrv\iisres.dll,-30501
@%ProgramFiles%\Hyper-V\SnapInAbout.dll,-211
@FirewallAPI.dll,-32752
```

**How do I convert these indirect strings to the actual group names *in managed code*?**

I'm trying to use [GetModuleHandle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683199(v=vs.85).aspx) to load the module/assembly and then use [LoadString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647486(v=vs.85).aspx) to load the string, but `LoadString` doesn't load the resource. Here's my code:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern int LoadString(IntPtr hInstance, uint uID, StringBuilder lpBuffer, int nBufferMax);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
private static extern uint GetLastError();

public static string GetGroupingFromResource(string resourceInfo)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(resourceInfo))
    {
        return resourceInfo;
    }

    var matches = Regex.Match(resourceInfo, @"^@([^,]+),-(\d+)$");
    if (! matches.Success)
    {
        return resourceInfo;
    }

    var modulePath = matches.Groups[1].Value;
    UInt32 resourceID;
    if (!UInt32.TryParse(matches.Groups[2].Value, out resourceID))
    {
        return resourceInfo;
    }

    resourceID += 10000;

    Console.Out.WriteLine(string.Format("Assembly Path: {0}", modulePath));
    Console.Out.WriteLine(string.Format("Resource ID:   {0}", resourceID));

    modulePath = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(modulePath);

    var searchPaths = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH").Split(';');
    if (! System.IO.Path.IsPathRooted(modulePath))
    {
        foreach (var searchPath in searchPaths)
        {
            var fullModulePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(searchPath, modulePath);
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(fullModulePath))
            {
                modulePath = fullModulePath;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    Console.Out.WriteLine(string.Format("Module Path: {0}", modulePath));
    var moduleHandle = GetModuleHandle(modulePath);
    var lastError = GetLastError();
    Console.Out.WriteLine("Last Error: {0}", lastError);
    if (lastError != 0x0)
    {
        return null;
    }

    var grouping = new StringBuilder();
    LoadString(moduleHandle, resourceID, grouping, 255);
    lastError = GetLastError();
    Console.Out.WriteLine("Last Error: {0}", lastError);
    if (lastError != Win32ErrorCodes.Ok)
    {
        return null;
    }

    Console.Out.WriteLine(grouping.ToString());
    return grouping.ToString();

}
```

Comment: you need use [SHLoadIndirectString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759919(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: on c++ code like this `WCHAR sz[1024];if (S_OK == SHLoadIndirectString(L"@FirewallAPI.dll,-32752", sz, RTL_NUMBER_OF(sz), 0)){..}`

Comment: @RbMm If you add that as an answer, I'll accept it. Not the C++ code, though.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("shlwapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true)]
        public static extern int SHLoadIndirectString(string pszSource, StringBuilder pszOutBuf, int cchOutBuf, IntPtr ppvReserved);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(1024);

            string resourcePath = "@FirewallAPI.dll,-32752";

            int result = SHLoadIndirectString(resourcePath, buffer, buffer.Capacity, IntPtr.Zero);

            if (result == 0) Console.WriteLine(buffer.ToString()); // return "Network Discovery" on Windows 10 (1607)

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```